# R: Scoping rules are getting me into murky waters

Tags: r, evaluation, scoping

Any help with this problem I'm having would be greatly appreciated.  I am a moderately advanced R programmer, but so far all my solutions have failed me.  I start with the logic behind what I am trying to do, followed by my attempt, followed by the test cases. I tried to be as explicit as possible.

I should probably mention that I sort of know what the problem is, but I don't know what the solution is.

```
# sqldf has some limitations:

cpaste <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", ")

dd <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
b <- 5:8

# this is what I want to get
sqldf("select * from dd where a in (5, 6, 7, 8)")

# but I want to get it by typing this
sqldf(sprintf("select * from %s where a in (%s)", dd, b)) # error

# and it doesn't work, because this is what sprintf expects:
sqldf(sprintf("select * from %s where a in (%s)", "dd", paste(b, collapse = ", ")))

# in other words, 
# (1) the name of data frame, not the data frame itself, and
# (2) the vector must be turned into a single string with comma separated values

# I wrote a wrapper function for sqldf
# it uses sprintf to create the sql string that I need to feed to sqldf
# but before doing that it does (1) and (2) as mentioned above
# so I can do this and it would work:
run_sql("select * from %s where a in (%s)", dd, b)

# it works until I try running it inside another funciton
# where I start running into some problems

# here's the function, followed by test cases

run_sql <- function(zcode = NULL, ..., display = TRUE, eval = TRUE) {

  require(sqldf)

  ellipsis <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
  ellipsis[1] <- NULL
  ellipsis$inline <- NULL
  ellipsis$display <- NULL
  ellipsis$eval <- NULL
  # print(ellipsis)
  # print(lapply(ellipsis, class))

  ffn <- function(x) {
    if (is.name(x)) { # the argument passed is itself a variable
      if (is.data.frame(eval(x))) {
        as.character(x) # returns just the name of the data frame
      } else if (is.atomic(eval(x))) {
        cpaste(eval(x)) # return the atomic vector as comma-sep string
      } else "_____FAIL1_____"
    } else if (is.call(x)) { # the argument passed is a function call, eg 2:4
      if (is.atomic(eval(x))) cpaste(eval(x)) else "_____FAIL2_____"
    } else {
      if (is.atomic(x)) cpaste(x) else "_____FAIL3_____"
    }
  }
  ellipsis <- lapply(ellipsis, ffn)

  zcode <- do.call(sprintf, unname(ellipsis))
  if (display == TRUE) cat(paste0(zcode, "\n\n"))

  if (eval == TRUE) {
    sqldf(zcode)
  } else {
    zcode
  }

}

dd <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
b <- 5:8
run_sql("select * from %s where a > %s", dd, 5)
run_sql("select * from %s where a in (%s)", dd, b)

# it works when the function uses variables in .GlobalEnv
# but this is not the preferred way:
foo <- function() {
  run_sql("select * from %s where a in (%s)", dd, b)
}
foo()

# here's the preferred way
# but things stop working:
foo <- function(x, y) {
  run_sql("select * from %s where a in (%s)", x, y)
}
foo(dd, b) 

# here's one solution to the above, but I am hoping there's a better way
foo <- function(x, y) {
  do.call(run_sql, list("select * from %s where a in (%s)", 
    substitute(x), 
    substitute(y)))
}
foo(dd, b) 

# also, the above solution does not work with local variables
foo <- function() {
  bb <- dd
  do.call(run_sql, list("select * from %s where a in (%s)", 
    bb, 
    substitute(y)))
}
foo()
```

Comment: Where's the `y` in the last non-working example?  Not a promise and not a local variable, and I don't see a global.  Also, what you're trying to do would seem to be a whole lot easier if you just use `[` to select the rows rather than `sqldf`.  Is there a compelling need for `sqldf` for your actual problem?

Comment: Where's the `cpaste` function?

Comment: I added the `cpaste` function.  Sorry about that.  The use case for this is that I'm have a lot of SQL code that I would have to rewrite otherwise.

Comment: Again, where's the `y` in the last non-working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@G. Grothendieck's solution will probably be easier for many readers of this post. That said, I think you can fix your function by identifying the parent environment of the call to `run_sql`, then using `envir=` to specify that environment anytime you call a function that depends on environments -- specifically, `eval()` and `sqldf()`. Like so:

```
cpaste <- function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", ")
run_sql <- function(zcode = NULL, ..., display = TRUE, eval = TRUE, envir=parent.frame()) {

  require(sqldf)

  ellipsis <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
  ellipsis[1] <- NULL
  ellipsis$inline <- NULL
  ellipsis$display <- NULL
  ellipsis$eval <- NULL
  # print(ellipsis)
  # print(lapply(ellipsis, class))

  ffn <- function(x) {
    if (is.name(x)) { # the argument passed is itself a variable
      if (is.data.frame(eval(x, envir=envir))) {
        as.character(x) # returns just the name of the data frame
      } else if (is.atomic(eval(x, envir=envir))) {
        cpaste(eval(x, envir=envir)) # return the atomic vector as comma-sep string
      } else "_____FAIL1_____"
    } else if (is.call(x)) { # the argument passed is a function call, eg 2:4
      if (is.atomic(eval(x, envir=envir))) cpaste(eval(x, envir=envir)) else "_____FAIL2_____"
    } else {
      if (is.atomic(x)) cpaste(x) else "_____FAIL3_____"
    }
  }
  ellipsis <- lapply(ellipsis, ffn)

  zcode <- do.call(sprintf, unname(ellipsis))
  if (display == TRUE) cat(paste0(zcode, "\n\n"))

  if (eval == TRUE) {
    sqldf(zcode, envir=envir)
  } else {
    zcode
  }

}
```

This works in your test case using x and y:

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
  run_sql("select * from %s where a in (%s)", x, y)
}
foo(dd, b)
```

And, with some tweaking, in a test case using `do.call` and local variables:

```
foo <- function(y) {
  bb <- dd
  do.call(run_sql, list("select * from %s where a in (%s)", 
                        as.name("bb"), 
                        substitute(y),
                        envir=environment()))
}
foo(b)
```

To understand the problem with your original function, and to understand what environment was visible to `eval()` each time it was called, I wrote a function called `enveval` to wrap several `sys.xxx` functions and the `eval()` call. Then, back in the `run_sql` function, I replaced all calls to `eval` with calls to `enveval`.

```
# enveval: Replace an eval() call with enveval() to see a description of the stack of environments experienced by eval()
enveval <- function(x, envir=parent.frame()) {
  cat(paste0("EVALUATING ",as.character(x),":\n"))
  stack <- data.frame(frame_num=1:sys.nframe(), call=strtrim(as.character(sys.calls()),15), 
                      is_eval_envir=NA, vars_in_frame=NA, x_exists=NA, eval_x=NA)
  for(i in 1:nrow(stack)) {
    f <- which(i==stack$frame_num)
    stack[f,"is_eval_envir"] <- identical(envir,sys.frame(f))
    stack[f,"vars_in_frame"] <- paste(ls(envir=sys.frame(f)),collapse=",")
    stack[f,"x_exists"] <- exists(as.character(x), where=sys.frame(f))
    if(stack[f,"is_eval_envir"] & stack[f,"x_exists"]) {
      # if all the variables to evaluate are single-element atomic, you can also run the following line:
      if(is.atomic(eval(x, envir=sys.frame(f)))) {
        stack[f,"eval_x"] <- cpaste(eval(x, envir=sys.frame(f)))
      } else {
        stack[f,"eval_x"] <- "[non-atomic]"
      }
    }
  }
  print(stack)
  eval(x, envir=envir)
}

# The new run_sql where eval is replaced with enveval:
run_sql <- function(zcode = NULL, ..., display = TRUE, eval = TRUE, envir=parent.frame()) {

  require(sqldf)

  ellipsis <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE))
  ellipsis[1] <- NULL
  ellipsis$inline <- NULL
  ellipsis$display <- NULL
  ellipsis$eval <- NULL
  # print(ellipsis)
  # print(lapply(ellipsis, class))

  ffn <- function(x) {
    if (is.name(x)) { # the argument passed is itself a variable
      if (is.data.frame(enveval(x, envir=envir))) {
        as.character(x) # returns just the name of the data frame
      } else if (is.atomic(enveval(x, envir=envir))) {
        cpaste(enveval(x, envir=envir)) # return the atomic vector as comma-sep string
      } else "_____FAIL1_____"
    } else if (is.call(x)) { # the argument passed is a function call, eg 2:4
      if (is.atomic(enveval(x, envir=envir))) cpaste(enveval(x, envir=envir)) else "_____FAIL2_____"
    } else {
      if (is.atomic(x)) cpaste(x) else "_____FAIL3_____"
    }
  }
  ellipsis <- lapply(ellipsis, ffn)

  zcode <- do.call(sprintf, unname(ellipsis))
  if (display == TRUE) cat(paste0(zcode, "\n\n"))

  if (eval == TRUE) {
    sqldf(zcode, envir=envir)
  } else {
    zcode
  }

}
```

Playing around with the test cases shows you what `enveval` sees (and what `eval` would have seen) each time it's called. For example, running the first test function:

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
  run_sql("select * from %s where a in (%s)", x, y)
}
foo(dd, b)
```

gave the following print-out showing that the frame for the `foo(dd, b)` call was the useful environment for every call to `eval()`:

```
EVALUATING x:
  frame_num            call is_eval_envir                         vars_in_frame x_exists       eval_x
1         1      foo(dd, b)          TRUE                                   x,y     TRUE [non-atomic]
2         2 run_sql("select         FALSE display,ellipsis,envir,eval,ffn,zcode    FALSE         <NA>
3         3 lapply(ellipsis         FALSE                                 FUN,X    FALSE         <NA>
4         4 FUN(X[[2]], ...         FALSE                                     x     TRUE         <NA>
5         5 is.data.frame(e         FALSE                                     x     TRUE         <NA>
6         6 enveval(x, envi         FALSE                     envir,f,i,stack,x     TRUE         <NA>
EVALUATING y:
  frame_num            call is_eval_envir                         vars_in_frame x_exists     eval_x
1         1      foo(dd, b)          TRUE                                   x,y     TRUE 5, 6, 7, 8
2         2 run_sql("select         FALSE display,ellipsis,envir,eval,ffn,zcode    FALSE       <NA>
3         3 lapply(ellipsis         FALSE                                 FUN,X    FALSE       <NA>
4         4 FUN(X[[3]], ...         FALSE                                     x    FALSE       <NA>
5         5 is.data.frame(e         FALSE                                     x    FALSE       <NA>
6         6 enveval(x, envi         FALSE                     envir,f,i,stack,x    FALSE       <NA>
EVALUATING y:
  frame_num            call is_eval_envir                         vars_in_frame x_exists     eval_x
1         1      foo(dd, b)          TRUE                                   x,y     TRUE 5, 6, 7, 8
2         2 run_sql("select         FALSE display,ellipsis,envir,eval,ffn,zcode    FALSE       <NA>
3         3 lapply(ellipsis         FALSE                                 FUN,X    FALSE       <NA>
4         4 FUN(X[[3]], ...         FALSE                                     x    FALSE       <NA>
5         5 enveval(x, envi         FALSE                     envir,f,i,stack,x    FALSE       <NA>
EVALUATING y:
  frame_num            call is_eval_envir                         vars_in_frame x_exists     eval_x
1         1      foo(dd, b)          TRUE                                   x,y     TRUE 5, 6, 7, 8
2         2 run_sql("select         FALSE display,ellipsis,envir,eval,ffn,zcode    FALSE       <NA>
3         3 lapply(ellipsis         FALSE                                 FUN,X    FALSE       <NA>
4         4 FUN(X[[3]], ...         FALSE                                     x    FALSE       <NA>
5         5 cpaste(enveval(         FALSE                                     x    FALSE       <NA>
6         6 paste(x, collap         FALSE                          collapse,sep    FALSE       <NA>
7         7 enveval(x, envi         FALSE                     envir,f,i,stack,x    FALSE       <NA>

select * from x where a in (5, 6, 7, 8)

a
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

Comment: That is a very thorough explanation.  I tried something similar to what you had, but failed.  But your approach shows me why mine failed.  Thanks a lot!  I really like the `enveval` function.  I will use it in the future for debugging stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you are looking for already exists in the gsubfn package which is automatically pulled in by sqldf. See [Example 5](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_5._Insert_Variables) on the [sqldf home page](http://sqldf.googlecode.com) for the way to do this and look at the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/vignettes/gsubfn.pdf) from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) for even more information on `fn`.  In terms of the present examples:

```
dd <- data.frame(a = 1:10)
ddname <- "dd"

b <- 5
fn$sqldf("select * from $ddname where a > $b")

b <- 5:8
fn$sqldf("select * from $ddname where a in (`toString(b)`)")
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much easier, but it's not quite there, since you did have to create $ddname.

Comment: Try: `ddinsert <- with(data.frame(a = 1:10), paste(paste("select", a, "a"), collapse = " union all ")); 
fn$sqldf("select a from ($ddinsert) where a > 5")`